# Spring-data-mongodb+Querydsl:How can build query from mongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I need excute something before repository query db, but I can't build a query like current repository

```
QuerydslRepositorySupport support = new QuerydslRepositorySupport(mongoTemplate) {
};
  SpringDataMongodbQuery sdmq=support.from(SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE.createPath(eInfo.getJavaType()))
    .where(booleanBuilder), countPageRequest, eInfo.getJavaType();
```

`SpringDataMongodbQuery` is not public,and `from` method is protected

Answer (score 0):

spring jira bug fix 1514， fix version 1.10 RC1

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1514